# Gradle multi-application WAR build file splitting into separate included files -- 'def' breaks it

Tags: gradle, groovy

Gradle build is used for eight applications.

At present, everything is dumped in a huge single build.gradle file.

I am trying to split it up into one Gradle file per application WAR build.

However, they all have in common a lot of 'def' usage.   The sharing of 'def' usage doesn't work for me.

I have read up on this as I don't know Groovy -- but 'def' won't play ball, seems special case when sharing stuff between Gradle files?

Error shows that 'def' reuse isn't working (it was fine when all in a huge single build.gradle file):

*Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: withSubsystemFiles for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.SingleParentCopySpec*

How to solve? (Or... is this a horrible build design? Open to alternative ways, too.)

File: **build.gradle**

```
//etc....

if ("foo".equals(  project.getProperty('application')  )) {
    apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/foo_application.gradle"
}

if ("bar".equals(  project.getProperty('application')  )) {
    apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/bar_application.gradle"
}

//etc... lots more applications to build
```

File:  **/gradle/foo_application.gradle**

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/include_def.gradle"

task fooApplicationWar(type: War) {  
    from "website/application_foo"

    webInf{
        with withSubsystemFiles
        with withSpecialResources
        with withServiceContext

        // then many   'from'   that are __unique__ to fooApplicationWar                
    }
    // etc...
}
```

File:  **/gradle/bar_application.gradle**

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/include_def.gradle"

task barApplicationWar(type: War) {  
    from "website/application_bar"

    webInf{
        with withSubsystemFiles
        with withSpecialResources
        with withServiceContext

        // then many   'from'   that are __unique__ to barApplicationWar                
    }
    // etc...
}
```

File:  **/gradle/include_def.gradle**

```
def withSubsystemFiles = copySpec {
    //-- Copy SubsystemFiles
}
def withSpecialResources = copySpec {
    //-- Copy SpecialResources
}
def withServiceContext = copySpec {
    //-- Copy ServiceContext
}
// etc... many many other 'def' that are common, shared by all application builds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `include_def.gradle`, define your copySpec like that :

```
ext.withSubsystemFiles = copySpec {
    //-- Copy SubsystemFiles
}
ext.withSpecialResources = copySpec {
    //-- Copy SpecialResources
}
ext.withServiceContext = copySpec {
    //-- Copy ServiceContext
}
```

If you want to define extra properties in your project, you have to use the [ExtraPropertiesExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html)